# Script to launch a linux terminal, wait 1s and then launch command in it

Tags: linux, bash, terminal, elementary-os

would like to automate showing of a nice weather report

```
curl wttr.in/bydgoszcz
```

[weather report](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RVw2s.png)

with such script launched from the system menu:

```
#!/bin/sh
exec io.elementary.terminal -e "curl wttr.in/bydgoszcz"
```

But this way the output gets a little "incomplete", just like if the command got executed too fast (notice where the `user@machine` line went here):

[weather report in the script](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nVbhO.png)

So, is there a way to delay the command after `-e` flag?

Or maybe totally different approach will automate this to show the output properly?

Answer (score 0):

im not sure but try this

exec io.elementary.terminal -e "sleep1s & curl wttr.in/bydgoszcz"

Comment: Also thought about it, but this opens terminal with a single dot as an output, and once I close it, the sessions restarts! (wtf?)
Here is a screenshot - https://imgur.com/1wrEgb4

Comment: ah okay, under a normal terminal it would do sleep 1 second and then execute the second comand, do u need curl? like wget have a wait time option wget --wait=seconds -qO-

Comment: did you mean `-e "sleep 1 && curl -s wttr.in/bydgoszcz"` ? (The single ampersand puts the sleep in the background; double ampersand waits for the sleep to finish successfully before running curl.)

Comment: @AlexxRoche, technically, the `&&` waits for the `sleep` to complete SUCCESSFULLY.  (if the sleep is killed, the curl would not execute.)  Since we don't really care whether the sleep is successful, we can just use a semicolon instead of `&&`

Answer (score 0):

Would

```
#!/bin/sh
WTTR=$(curl -s wttr.in/bydgoszcz) && \
exec io.elementary.terminal -e "echo $WTTR"
```

solve the problem?

Comment: Almost there. The output is complete, but also mashed up - https://imgur.com/zjf61y1

Comment: That happens when the string being sent to echo isn't quoted. Try `echo "$WTTR"`

Comment: When doublequoted - `-e "echo "$WTTR""` - the output is single word - `weather`
When tried `-e 'echo "$WTTR" '` - output is `$WTTR`
When tried `-e echo "$WTTR"` - the output is empty line